# Brezze.js - Query fail if I use .Include

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have following javascript in my ViewModel:

```
 manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (projects) {
                projects.results.forEach(function (item) {
                    if (item.IsFavorite() == true) {
                        self.favoriten.push(item);
                    }
                    else {
                        self.zuletzt.push(item);
                    }                        
                });
                console.log("Query favorite finished");
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log("Query failed: " + error.message);
            });
```

The Controller:

```
var res = _contextProvider.Context.Projects
            .Include("User11")
            .Include("User12")
            .Include("Timestamps")
            .Where(p => p.Finished == false)
            .Where(p => p.User12.Any(u => u.Guid == ID));

var erg = res.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamps.Min(t => t.Start));

return erg;
```

I get an error: Query failed: + a lot of Data
If I remove the three Include statements the query work, but the odrderBy does not work.

Is there a solution?

Comment: This looks to be more of an Entity Framework question than a Breeze question ... so I added the EF tag. You might get quicker/better help from that community

Comment: Does this query work in plain EF?

Comment: What do you mean with plain EF?

Comment: I found out, that the OrderBy clause also work without "Include("Timestamps")